# Objective-C: In-App Messaging buttons' action

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, urbanairship.com

I'm implementing Urban Airship's Interactive Notifications, following UA's [docs](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios/#ios-custom-interactive-notifications). I have succeeded registering category and actions, like bellow:

```
// Define category options foreground and none
UANotificationActionOptions optionsActions = ( UANotificationActionOptionForeground );
UANotificationActionOptions optionsNone = ( UANotificationActionOptionNone );
UANotificationCategoryOptions optionCategory = ( UANotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction );

// Define cancel action for all categories
UANotificationAction *actionCancel = [UANotificationAction actionWithIdentifier: @"action_cancel"
                                                                          title: @"Cancel"
                                                                        options: optionsNone];

// Define post action for the post category
UANotificationAction *actionPost = [UANotificationAction actionWithIdentifier: @"action_post"
                                                                        title: @"Post"
                                                                      options: optionsActions];

// Actions of post category
NSArray<UANotificationAction *> *actionsPost = @[actionPost, actionCancel];

// Define the post category
UANotificationCategory *post = [UANotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier: @"post_cancel"
                                                                      actions: actionsPost
                                                            intentIdentifiers: @[]
                                                                      options: optionCategory];

// Set the custom categories
[UAirship push].customCategories = [NSSet setWithArray:@[post]];
```

Now, I'm trying build an In-App Messaging with those buttons (post & cancel) and my buttons are already appearing when I set message's [buttonGroup](https://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/Classes/UAInAppMessage.html#/c:objc(cs)UAInAppMessage(py)buttonGroup). Unfortunately, I've could not figure out how can I link custom actions for each button, I don't know which dictionary I should pass in message's [buttonActions](https://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/Classes/UAInAppMessage.html#/c:objc(cs)UAInAppMessage(py)buttonActions).

```
UAInAppMessage *message = [UAInAppMessage new];
message.displayType = UAInAppMessageDisplayTypeBanner;
message.position = UAInAppMessagePositionTop;

message.duration = 5.0;

message.alert = @"My alert"
message.primaryColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
message.secondaryColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UAInAppMessaging *inAppMessaging = [UAInAppMessaging new];

[message setButtonGroup: @"post_cancel"]; // this line ensure that my in-app messaging add my two registered buttons
[message setButtonActions: /* WHICH DICTIONARY SHOULD I PASS? */ ];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [inAppMessaging displayMessage: message];
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expects a dictionary of button IDs to a map of action names to values. Example:

```
@{
  @"action_cancel":
       @{
           @"my_custom_action_name": @"custom action value",
           @"another_action_name": @(YES)
       },

   @"action_post":
       @{
           @"some_other_action_name": @"some other action value"
       }
}
```

That will run `my_custom_action_name` and `another_action_name` when the in-app `action_cancel` button is tapped.